# Animate ngx-bootstrap progressbar

Tags: angular, animation, progress-bar, ngx-bootstrap

The dynamic value progressbar example has an animation where the colored bar value fills up.

Is it possible to have that animation effect (filling up the bar), with a static value?

I tried adding [animate]="false" and that did not work.

The progressbar seems to load at the value.

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/progressbar#bs3-dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but feels like a hack :)

```
//Component:
value: number = 0;
ngOnInit() {
   setTimeout(() => this.value = 20, 0)
}

//Template:
<progressbar [value]="value"></progressbar>
```

And do not use  [animate]="false", it won't animate if you use it.